# How do I catch ES6 Promise rejections and completely stop flow?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Say I have 4 functions: `runA()`, `runB()`, `runC()` and `runD()`.

Using ES6 promises, in a completely successful run, these would all be run one after another:

```
runA()
.then(runB)
.then(runC)
.then(runD)
```

If `runA` or `runB` fail (reject or throw), I would like to call `error1()` and then completely stop the chain (not call `runC` or `runD` ). This makes me think I should add a single `.catch()` at the very end of the `.then` promise chain:

```
runA()
.then(runB)
.then(runC)     //won't get called if runA or runB throws
.then(runD)     //won't get called if runA or runB throws
.catch(error1)
```

But if `runC` fails, I would like to call `error2()` and still stop the chain (not call `runD`).

```
runA()
.then(runB)   
.catch(error1)  //moved up to only handle runA and runB
.then(runC)     //but now this gets called after error1() is run
.then(runD)     
.catch(error2)
```

Now that I have 2 `catch` calls in the chain, `runC` will get called after `error1` is run since the result of the catch will default to a `resolve`. Is my only option to have the `error1` function create a promise that it always rejects?

Comment: What's wrong with using only one `.catch()`? You can do error triage in the catch callback (`if (error1) error1() else if (error2) error2()...`). The `Error` object you throw can have a message and a name (could be the type like you need, 'RunCError' for example).

Comment: of course, you meant `runA()
.then(runB)
.then(runC)
.then(runD)` - ... other than that, if you **really** can not determine what caused the error, you can `throw` at the end of `error1` to skip past `runC` and `runD` - but you'll need to determine in `error2` that the error came from A or B rather than C or D anyway

Answer (score 4):

No, having `error1` create a promise that always rejects, is ***not*** your only option.

You can exploit the fact that `.then` takes two arguments:

```
.then(onSuccess, onFailure)
```

When given two arguments, there's an under-appreciated effect that `onFailure` will ***not*** catch failures in `onSuccess`. This is usually undesirable, except here, where you can use this fact to branch your decision tree:

```
runA()
.then(runB)
.then(() => runC().then(runD), error1)
.catch(error2)
```

This does what you want.

- if `runA` or `runB` fail, then `error1` is called and chain stops.
- if `runC` or `runD` fail, then `error2` is called and chain stops.

You can also write it like this:

```
runA()
.then(runB)
.then(() => runC()
  .then(runD)
  .catch(error2),
error1)
```

```js
var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;

// Change which one of these four rejects, to see behavior:
var runA = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => log("a"));
var runB = () => Promise.reject().then(() => log("b"));
var runC = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => log("c"));
var runD = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => log("d"));
var error1 = () => log("error1");
var error2 = () => log("error2");

runA()
.then(runB)
.then(() => runC().then(runD), error1)
.catch(error2)
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Try modifying which one fails in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3vwfhzp).

Comment: Definitely a useful technique, and the one I tried to jump to at first.

My problem with this is that if I want to catch an exception or rejection further up in the chain, the error callback from the 2nd `then` parameter will cause the outer chain to resolve...unless that error callback itself threw another exception or rejected, in which case, it would cause the next catch statement to be hit, neither of which are really what I might want to happen. 

I've [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3vwfhzp/4/) here with the example issue.

Comment: Well it won't work unless you follow my answer obviously. You have to branch the chain like i show in my fiddle,  and you're not doing that.

Comment: Take another look. I did branch it, but with another `then` statement following the branch. So your answer only works of the branch is the next to last part of the chain.

Comment: My solution has the four functions you asked about. If you want to reject an outer chain, with what error should it be rejected? If you just want to stop the chain without success or failure, you could do `.then(new Promise())`, but that is rarely a good idea, even though I'm trying not to judge.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using only one `.catch()`? You can do error triage in the catch callback (`if (error1) error1() else if (error2) error2()...`). The `Error` object you throw can have a message and a name (could be the type like you need, 'RunCError' for example).

```
runA()
    .then(runB)
    .then(runC)     // won't get called if runA or runB throws
    .then(runD)     // won't get called if runA or runB throws
    .catch(handleErrors)

function runA() {
    // ...

    if (err) {
        var error = new Error('Something is wrong...');
        error.name = 'RunAError';
        throw error;
    }
}

function runB() {
    // ...

    if (err) {
        var error = new Error('Something is wrong...');
        error.name = 'RunBError';
        throw error;
    }
}

function runC() {
    // ...

    if (err) {
        var error = new Error('Something is wrong...');
        error.name = 'RunCError';
        throw error;
    }
}

function runD() {
    // ...

    if (err) {
        var error = new Error('Something is wrong...');
        error.name = 'RunDError';
        throw error;
    }
}

function handleErrors(err) {
    if (err.name == 'RunAError') {
        handleAError();
    }

    if (err.name == 'RunBError') {
        handleBError();
    }

    // so on...
}
```

Comment: So is it rare that you would want to use more than 1 catch in a promise chain?And if you do include more than 1 `catch`, and you don't want the next `then` to get fired after that catch, the function inside the catch needs to throw or reject again.

Comment: Yes. It's very much like synchronous code. If you catch an exception, then it's caught, handled, and positive code flow resumes. That's what catch is for. If that's not what you want, then either don't catch it to begin with, or rethrow it. In that case if you nest catches then you'd expect the outer ones to catch it too, right?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on the same problem and my solution is so far to explicitly invoke a `reject` in a `catch` like in this js bin: https://jsbin.com/yaqicikaza/edit?js,console

Code snippet

```js
const promise1 = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => reject( 42 ) );

promise1
  .catch( ( err ) => console.log( err ) ) // 42 will be thrown here
  .then( ( res ) => console.log( 'will execute' ) ) // then branch will execute


const promise2 = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => reject( 42 ) );

promise2
  .catch( ( err ) => Promise.reject( ) ) // trigger rejection down the line
  .then( ( res ) => console.log( 'will not execute' ) ) // this will be skipped
```